# Fill instance variable with all Users from table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, instance-variables

I want to fill an instance variable with all my Groups names.

How do I do this?

```
@groups = Group.name.all
```

Obviously, this doesn't work. But I don't even know what to search for.
The table is called groups, the field name. I am doing this from a different controller but I can see the groups if I use

```
@groups = Group.first.name
```

So the associations seem to work.

Comment: Just to be pedantic, there's no associations going on here at all.  An association would be a link to another table using a foreign key field.

Comment: @MarcusJanietz: This is more efficient: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30933957/3185510

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@groups = Group.all.map(&:name)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
@groups = Group.pluck(:name)
```

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck

`Group.all` will load all of the groups table data, and instantiate full models out of them, just to get the names.  This is slow and memory intensive.  `pluck` just gets the data you need out of the db in the first place and so is much more efficient.